# Plantilla de bootstrap no funciona en .net mvc con razor

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo una plantilla con bootstrap y funciona bien, pero cuando quise implementar el menú de arriba en .net mvc en el layout, no me funciona, cómo debo poner los link rel y los script? en la plantilla tengo unos arriba y otros al final

Arriba

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="jq/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jq/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header collapse navbar-collapse">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">navbar-inverse</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <img src="ims/logo2.jpg" height="50" width="50"> 
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li ><a href="#">Solicitudes</a></li> <!--class="active" -->
            <li><a href="#">Certificados</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Administrativo</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">Reportes</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">Estado de Trámites</a></li>   
            <li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</li>  
            <li><button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn navbar-right">Iniciar Sesión</button>   </li>      
          </ul>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Abajo

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

La parte del menú creo que es así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css">

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">navbar-inverse</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <img src="ims/logo2.jpg" height="50" width="50">
                </div>

                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Solicitudes", "Index", "Solicitudes")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Certificados", "Index", "Certificados")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Administrativo", "Index", "Administrativo")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reportes", "Index", "Reportes")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Estado de Trámites", "Index", "Estado de Trámite")</li>
                        <li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</li>
                        <li><button>@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Cerrar", "Sesion", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary navbar-btn navbar-right" })</button></li>
                    </ul>

                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>
```

En la parte de scripts agregué los que no son enlaces externos y hasta actualicé bootstrap en nuget

Así se ve la vista que trato de usar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregué algo al bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap-theme.css",
                      "~/Scripts/style3.css",
                      "~/Scripts/estilos.css"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en que yo había adicionado las librerías de las plantillas sin quitar las que VS trae por defecto.

Las eliminé todas, agregué las de la plantilla, actualicé bootstrap y eliminé las que eran iguales a las de la plantilla para que fueran estas las que quedaran.

Ahora todo funciona bien.